# Spring 3 doesn't inject DAO bean

Tags: spring, javabeans, dao

I'm using Spring 3 and `UserServiceImpl`. The service does not see the `Dao` bean.

This is my `UserDao`:

```
    @Repository
    public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return this.sessionFactory;
        }

        @Autowired
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        private Session currentSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
    }
```

Then the Service bean :

```
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
        @Autowired
        private UserDao userDao;

        public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
            this.userDao = userDao;
        }


        public String testeoDAO() {
            return userDao.funciona();
        }
    }
```

The testeoDAO method had writeen only for testing the DAO.The applicationContext

```
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.apress.usermanager.dao.hibernate.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="com.apress.usermanager.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.apress.usermanager"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
                hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
                hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
                hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1=1"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="staticDataImporter" class="com.apress.usermanager.support.StaticDataImporter" depends-on="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="staticData" value="classpath:default-data.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

And the error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.apress.usermanager.service.UserServiceImpl.testeoDAO(UserServiceImpl.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Comment: Where do you call the testeDao method? Did you write a unit test for that? Do you run the program to test it and if so, how do you load the context?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.a,com.b">
</context:component-scan>
```

To scan package `com.a` and `com.b`. This allows the `classpath scan` and add all `@Component` and so forth to it.

Annote `UserServiceImpl` with `@Service`.

Regards.

Comment: And is not the same? `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.apress.usermanager" />`

Comment: that is to add to sessionfactory

Comment: tHANKS! My question if it is the same is for the property in sessionFactory : packagesToScan I read from the book 'Spring in Action' that the same that context:component-scan...

Comment: @marthaSibretti it is the answer?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, neither with context:componet-scan.... I'm very confused because I am follow the basic Dao Implementation with Hibernate 3 using contextual session, Spring 3 and it is very simple.

Comment: the packagesToScan property for the sessionFactory bean will look for domain classes, e.g. Book or Author that it can let Hibernate perform ORM for. It has nothing to do with creating a instance of your DAO bean

Comment: I think I'm confused mixing annotation-config with bean declarative xml. If I remove all the @Autowire, then the component scan,that UDO said,and the context:annotation-config, is innecesary, isn't it? Because I want to start with the simple example. I declare all my beans and injections in the applicatonContext.xml bty setter method.

Comment: If you declare one bean in XML and the same one in Component, I think there will be declared twice (2 of them).

Comment: Yes, I think so, I remove all the annotation and I declare `<bean id="userTesteo" class="com.apress.usermanager.dao.hibernate.UserTesteoImpl"/> <bean id="userDao" class="com.apress.usermanager.dao.hibernate.UserDaoImpl"> <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> </bean> <bean id="userService" class="com.apress.usermanager.service.UserServiceImpl"> <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" /> <property name="userTesteo" ref="userTesteo"/> </bean>` when userTesteo return only String and: `java.lang.NullPointerException ...`.